# Django Package Name importing

Tags: python, django

This is where my installed app lives:

```
INSTALLED_APPS += [
    'project.apps.packagename'

]
```

But I would like to reference it like so:

```
from packagename import SomeClass
```

at the moment this I have to do this

```
from project.apps.packagename import SomeClass
```

Is there a way in Django I can do something like this:

```
   INSTALLED_APPS += [
        'project.apps.packagename' as packagename

    ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

INSTALLED_APPS doesn't have anything to do with how you import modules in your code. That's just Python, so you'll need to modify the PYTHONPATH if you want to import apps directly. You can do this with `sys.path.append('/full/path/to/apps')` - bear in mind you'll want to do it both for development (probably in `manage.py`) and in production (in the .wsgi file).

Comment: Daniel, what's your timezone? Do you sleep?